# Leaflet Customer Marker Changes Position with Scale

Tags: leaflet, zoom, markers

I am using a customer marker to represent metro stops in my leaflet map. The problem is that the markers are changing their position every time I zoom in or out. When I finally zoom in to the last level they reach their specified position. How can I make them stay at the same place at all times like the default leaflet markers? The icon anchor option isn't working for me. Which option or property am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this issue by just deleting/not specifying the `iconAnchor` property of the custom icon. Then the 'icon's center' will always remain at the correct position by default.